# Code is not signed at all

Tags: ios, xcode

I have set my correct team , created the provisioning profile both for development and distribution for my new project and set all my icons. When it comes running the project , it stills warns

Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

and show the following message :

```
/Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TEST-fbjodlablxmpjahfncbidoqepfyx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TEST.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/larrylo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TEST-fbjodlablxmpjahfncbidoqepfyx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TEST.app/AppIcon29x29@2x.png
```

Would you please tell me what conditions or settings I have to check ?

Comment: You are trying to build (to your phone) or run distribution?

Comment: Yes , for ad-hoc distribution

Comment: As I remember, i got the same error with you one or twice. You can try to clean this project (cmd + k) and clean build folder (cmd + shift + k), remove your apple acc on xcode preference -> quit xcode -> open it again and add your acc again. Then try to rebuild

Comment: how to remove my apple acc on xcode preference  ?

Comment: Also fails ..not working

Comment: hummmmm, let's me check

Answer (score 2):

Code object is not signed at all error mostly relates to corrupt frameworks. So you download them again and problem resolves.

But in your case it looks like error caused by AppIcon29x29@2x.png oddly. Maybe delete it or change it?

Comment: I have used this to create icon and copy whole set to my xcode. still now working

Comment: Did you change the icon? After change or delete clean build your project and try again.

Comment: no, I have to create a new project and fit to see if I can fix this

Comment: I removed PaddleMas ( v1.18) from my cocoapods and this problem went away.  Have logged a bug to suggest Apple provide better error messaging.  Also make sure you clean the project and restart xcode when you do this for bonus points. also did you try removing your images to see if its a corrupted image file

Comment: I had to re-install the affected pod (remove it from project/Pods directory and do a `pod install`) to make it work again.